# Count of like on an opengraph object

Tags: yammer

I try to get a count of likes on an open graph object on #yammer.  I have a like button on an intranet page:

```
 yam.connect.actionButton({
        container: "#embedded-like",
        network: "xxxxx.com",   
        action: "like"
    });
```

When I click the button it seems to work, it is keeping his like/unliked status.

However when I check the JSON response of url: https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/my_feed.json, the liked_by count always stays at 0.

Is this a bug or am I looking at the wrong place?

Thnx